# PHP | What do I do when I have the register and login button's in the same page?

Tags: authentication

So on my website, http://vobern.com/ I have the register and login in the same page.

What could I do to make the Register function one thing, and the Login another.

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry, but you need to be much more specific in your question. On your site, I noticed you have two forms that both POST to the same page. If you are asking how can the PHP script distinguish which action was performed (a login or register), then I would suggest you create a hidden input field for each form called `type`, with values called `register` and `login`. Finally, your PHP script should read that POST variable `$_POST['type']`, so that it will know which form was submitted.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking, thanks.